# integral whose limit is measure of a set

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $(X,M,\mu)$ be a measure space and $f \in L^{1}(X,\mu)$. Then show that for $E \in M$, $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \int_{E} |f|^{1/k} = \mu(E)$. I am able to show this in the case that $\mu(E) < \infty$, but I do not know how to proceed when $\mu(E) = \infty$. For the sets of finite measure, we can use $ ||f||_{1} \cdot \chi_{E} \in L^{1}$ as a bound a use dominated convergence.

Comment: I don't agree with $\lVert f\rVert_1\chi_E$ dominating $\lvert f\rvert^{1/k}\chi_E$. However, $\left(\chi_{f^{-1}[-1,1]}\vee f\right)\chi_E$ does. More importantly, I don't agree with the thesis: if anything, I'd say $$\lim_{k\to\infty} \int_E\lvert f\rvert^{1/k}\,d\mu=\mu(E\setminus f^{-1}(0))$$

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

As noted by Gae. S. one may have to assume that $\mu(|f|=0)=0$.

I will assume that the space is $\sigma$-finite, then some finite measure $E_{n}$ are such that $E_{n}\uparrow$ and $E=\displaystyle\bigcup_{n}E_{n}$.

Therefore, 
\begin{align*}
\liminf_{k\rightarrow\infty}\int_{E}|f|^{1/k}&\geq\liminf_{k\rightarrow\infty}\int_{E_{n}}|f|^{1/k}\\
&=\mu(E_{n}),
\end{align*}
now taking $n\rightarrow\infty$ you get
\begin{align*}
\liminf_{k\rightarrow\infty}\int_{E}|f|^{1/k}\geq\mu(E)=\infty,
\end{align*}
and hence
\begin{align*}
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\int_{E}|f|^{1/k}=\infty.
\end{align*}

**Edit:**

The $\sigma$-finiteness can be removed by the following trick:

Since $f\in L^{1}$, we know that $(0<|f|<\infty)$ is $\sigma$-finite by considering it as the union of $(1/n<|f|<\infty)$, each of these is of finite measure. And we know that $|f|<\infty$ $\mu$-a.e. as well.

So we start with the integral that
\begin{align*}
\int_{E}|f|^{1/k}d\mu=\int_{E\cap(0<|f|<\infty)}|f|^{1/k}d\mu,
\end{align*}
and apply the $\sigma$-finiteness technique just proved above.

Comment: Is the claim true without the assumption of $\sigma$-finiteness?

Comment: @user100101212, you may look at how I get away from it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the assertion needs to have a little change:

Without loss of generality, we can treat $E$ as $X$. No $\sigma$-finiteness is assumed. We have
\begin{align*}
\int|f|^{1/k}d\mu=\int_{0<|f|<1}|f|^{1/k}d\mu+\int_{|f|\geq 1}|f|^{1/k}d\mu.
\end{align*}
On $(0<|f|<1)$, $|f|^{1/k}\leq|f|^{1/(k+1)}$, so 
\begin{align*}
\int_{0<|f|<1}|f|^{1/k}d\mu\rightarrow\int_{0<|f|<1}d\mu=\mu(0<|f|<1).
\end{align*}
On the other hand, on $(|f|\geq 1)$, $|f|^{1/(k+1)}\leq |f|^{1/k}\leq|f|$, we have 
\begin{align*}
\int_{|f|\geq 1}(|f|-|f|^{1/k})d\mu\rightarrow\int_{|f|\geq 1}(|f|-1)d\mu,
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\int_{|f|\geq 1}|f|^{1/k}d\mu\rightarrow\int_{|f|\geq 1}d\mu=\mu(|f|\geq 1).
\end{align*}
Note that we have canceled both sides the real number $\displaystyle\int_{|f|\geq 1}|f|$, this is allowed as $f\in L^{1}$.

We conclude that 
\begin{align*}
\int|f|^{1/k}d\mu\rightarrow\mu(0<|f|<1)+\mu(|f|\geq 1)=\mu(|f|>0).
\end{align*}